# How to load external xml file in cordova app

Tags: ios, xml, cordova

I built an app for ios and android 2 years ago where I load and display data from an external xml file.

I am trying to make an updated app, and the data is not showing.  Has anything changed with how this is handled in the last couple years?   I have tried adding the Network Status plugin as it seems like the issue might be connecting to the data.

I have tried adding access origin="*" to all config.xml files as that was usually my problem before.

This is the code I am using:

```
else {/* code for IE6, IE5 */ xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.example.com/example.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("order");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
    document.write("<div class=\"bar\"><center><a href=\"");  
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);   
    document.write("\" data-ajax=\"false\" ><img src=\"images/icon-"); 
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("item")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);       
    document.write(".png\"></a></center></div><br><br>");   
}
```

Comment: What version of cordova and platforms are you now using ?

Comment: cordova version 11.0.0 
installed platforms - ios 6.2.0, android 10.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Yes things have changed a bit due to WKWebView and security

For iOS, use [cordova-plugin-ios-xhr](https://github.com/globules-io/cordova-plugin-ios-xhr) and set your preferences to

```
  <preference name="allowFileAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
  <preference name="allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
```

You can also add these preferences to load external urls

```
  <preference name="AllowUntrustedCerts"  value="true" />
  <preference name="InterceptRemoteRequests" value="all" />
```

For Android, set your preferences to

```
 <preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />
```

Comment: With this I am able to load a local xml file and display data, but if I try to load an external xml from a website then it is still not working.   Am I missing a setting?   

I installed that plugin for ios, added the preferences to config.xml and did a build.   For android I just added the preference.   Same result on both.

Comment: There are other preferences you need to set up to load XML from  website. Will edit answer.

Comment: Answer edited...

Comment: Still can't load external file.   Could it have anything to do with other settings in config?  there seem to be multiple config files, I am editing all of them, and then doing a build just to be sure I get them all.     <content src="index.html" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <access origin="*" />

Comment: What is the error reporting from the fetch ?

Comment: https://vjcdesigns.com/clients/gongwer/errorlog.txt

Comment: you can see what app looks like by going to https://vjcdesigns.com/clients/gongwer/.   it pulls local xml on index to get icons for primary and general.   for general i have it pull a list from a local file.  primary still uses the external so you can see the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240894/discussion-between-vjamesv-and-eric).

Comment: This works for Android, ios is still not loading data from an external site